# How can I change the order of a coulmn in my dataframe and then order another column in a descending order?

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) like this:

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("Alistipes_species", "Bifidobacterium_longum", 
                              "Alistipes_indistinctus", "Intestinimonas_butyriciproducens", 
                              "Alistipes_putredinis", "Alistipes_indistinctus", "Archaea", 
                              "Bifidobacterium_longum", "Bifidobacterium_pseudocatenulatum", 
                              "Archaea", "Bacteroides_intestinalis", "Escherichia_coli", 
                              "Bifidobacterium_longum", "Ruminococcus_lactaris", "Bifidobacterium_pseudocatenulatum", 
                              "Alistipes_finegoldii", "Bacteroides_intestinalis", "Archaea", 
                              "Alistipes_species", "Alistipes_putredinis", "Alistipes_species", 
                              "Escherichia_coli", "Ruminococcus_lactaris", "Intestinimonas_butyriciproducens", 
                              "Intestinimonas_butyriciproducens", "Bifidobacterium_longum", 
                              "Escherichia_coli", "Alistipes_indistinctus", "Alistipes_species", 
                              "Escherichia_coli"), estimate = c(2.993713792394192, 
                                                                2.898363530604381, 2.80768573218585, 2.768556717138591, 2.703408405087247, 
                                                                2.697217086402023, 2.681566492267408, 2.655837994494677, 2.634723446174458, 
                                                                2.611578849399227, 2.606454283338246, 2.60138856314202, 2.59992441707176, 
                                                                2.591776576712751, 2.54911587464746, 2.543184731465986, 2.540999117857751, 
                                                                2.536116333751914, 2.523873598316934, 2.523084639094317, 2.512104325226928, 
                                                                2.491999251935198, 2.489993591045929, 2.477706677740445, 2.475851363277598, 
                                                                2.473104645687625, 2.467776750034647, 2.463229748648633, 2.461844173718993, 
                                                                2.457142741699132), se = c(0.128000535135637, 0.0918851049645649, 
                                                                                           0.1233462176465, 0.0999419585091611, 0.0629232046633574, 0.098726054301162, 
                                                                                           0.062700774509198, 0.054039253045018, 0.119881184467986, 0.0974227638762964, 
                                                                                           0.0619894062327098, 0.0619444165716709, 0.0972585850061383, 0.0463899973152548, 
                                                                                           0.0965797354432424, 0.0422308905008305, 0.118350714917976, 0.086472226737436, 
                                                                                           0.0459691308167419, 0.118085957892054, 0.0862100404520249, 0.0859997532019068, 
                                                                                           0.117620349275521, 0.0457122426108767, 0.0527335546149561, 0.045191176864539, 
                                                                                           0.117324812728395, 0.0608628988963404, 0.09555382610613, 0.04560544159049
                                                                ), country = c("Sweden", "Kazakhstan", "Sweden", "Austria", "Denmark", 
                                                                               "Metaanalysis", "Denmark", "Ireland", "Sweden", "Austria", "Denmark", 
                                                                               "Denmark", "Austria", "England", "Austria", "China", "Sweden", 
                                                                               "Kazakhstan", "England", "Sweden", "Metaanalysis", "Kazakhstan", 
                                                                               "Sweden", "England", "Ireland", "Japan", "Metaanalysis", "Denmark", 
                                                                               "Austria", "England")), yi.names = "yi", vi.names = "vi", digits = c(est = 4, 
                                                                                                                                                    se = 4, test = 4, pval = 4, ci = 4, var = 4, sevar = 4, fit = 4, 
                                                                                                                                                    het = 4), row.names = c(4L, 31L, 2L, 80L, 15L, 73L, 23L, 66L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            8L, 81L, 17L, 18L, 77L, 48L, 78L, 83L, 5L, 35L, 40L, 3L, 28L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            30L, 12L, 46L, 69L, 54L, 6L, 14L, 75L, 42L), class = c("escalc", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "data.frame"))
```

It has 4 columns. The 4th column is "Country". You can see the country names are not in any order. When I use `arrange` function either it starts with **Austria** or it starts with **Sweden**.  But I want to change this order. I want it to be arranged it in a way so that the rows with "Metaanalysis" come to the top and then the rest may be in any order.

After that, the values in the "estimate" column should be changed in a descending order keeping the order in the "country" column same, i.e., keeping rows with metaanalysis at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `match` within the `arrange` function. Arrange also works chronologically. The first argument is arranged and then the second while maintaining the first. If there is a third column to arrange by, then it will first consider the first column, then the side, and finally the third.

```
library(dplyr)

arrange(df, match(country, "Metaanalysis"), desc(estimate))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `arrange` the data with logical values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(country != 'Metaanalysis', desc(estimate))

#                                name estimate         se      country
#1             Alistipes_indistinctus 2.697217 0.09872605 Metaanalysis
#2                  Alistipes_species 2.512104 0.08621004 Metaanalysis
#3                   Escherichia_coli 2.467777 0.11732481 Metaanalysis
#4                  Alistipes_species 2.993714 0.12800054       Sweden
#5             Bifidobacterium_longum 2.898364 0.09188510   Kazakhstan
#6             Alistipes_indistinctus 2.807686 0.12334622       Sweden
#7   Intestinimonas_butyriciproducens 2.768557 0.09994196      Austria
#8               Alistipes_putredinis 2.703408 0.06292320      Denmark
#9                            Archaea 2.681566 0.06270077      Denmark
#10            Bifidobacterium_longum 2.655838 0.05403925      Ireland
#...
#...
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. can you please explain how your code works actually?

Comment: If you sort the logical values (`sort(c(TRUE, FALSE))`), you'll see that `FALSE` value gets sorted first than the `TRUE` value, the same logic is applied here. `country != 'Metaanalysis'` returns `FALSE` for value which is `'Metaanalysis'` hence it gets sorted first.